# Exit the script after being launched by crontab

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cron

I'm trying to make this work with crontab by running: node /home/.../test-reset.js :

```
const io = require('socket.io-client')
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3002');
socket.emit('message', 'reset');
process.exit(1);
```

It closes without sending the 'message' command.

Then I tested this:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client')
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3002');
socket.emit('message', 'reset');
setTimeout( function() { process.exit(1); } , 2000);
```

Here it works well but I do not like this practice with setTimeout.
You do not have an idea to make a clean exit without setTimeout?

I would like to close the script after it is launched and executed.

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for sending with acknowledgement:

```
socket.emit('message', 'reset', () => {
  process.exit(1);
});
```

[`socket.emit(eventName[, …args][, ack])`](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack):

> The ack argument is optional and will be called with the server answer.

This should call the callback as soon the emit was successfully performed and the acknowledgment was received.

On the receiving side you need:

```
socket.on('message', (val, fn) => {
  fn();
});
```